# The Red Book of Westmarch - Gold or Silver?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, the-hobbit

A friend of mine is designing a box to look like the Red Book of Westmarch. We could use the movies as a reference, but I was wondering if it's ever mentioned anywhere in the text whether or not the star and 'BB' initials are inlaid with gold or silver. I've poured through the appendices, and some of Tolkien's notes, but I've not found anything. Personally I feel that Bilbo would have went with gold, but I'm not sure.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can't find any mention about this, but I would say mithril (which ressembles silver), that metal was by far the most prized metal in middle-earth. It is also the metal used in Bilbo's mail coat. And the elves had a special reverence for Varda's silver stars, we know how Bilbo loved elves... well, that's only a guess, so I won't make it an official answer, hope someone have something more accurate.

Comment: After glancing at a few covers of pre-Gutenberg manuscripts, it looks like, for books that *have* anything but ornamentation on the cover the title would be the largest element. The author's name is often not present on the cover at all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the text, there's no mention of a star or "BB" at all. In Book I, Chapter 1, "A Long-Expected Party", the book is simply described as "a leather-bound manuscript"; in Book VI, Chapter 6, "Many Partings", we're told that they have become

> three books of lore that he had made at various times, written in his spidery hand, and labelled on their red backs...

Finally, in Book VI, Chapter 9, "The Grey Havens", it's described as "a big book with **plain red leather covers**" (emphasis added).

Based on this, the book seems to envision something with no decoration at all—no "BB" nor decorative star nor anything else.

Comment: For the LoTR and Hobbit, you're absolutly right. But I'm not sure about HoME and other writings. But this question has prompted my curiosity, and I did research on Google, there is a very passionate man called Hari Istvan who created a handwritten version of the book, he did much  research about it and his book is very simple, with no writting whatsoever. Still very beautiful.

Comment: In *The Return of the Shadow*, which contains the discussion of the beginning of *The Fellowship of the Ring*, it appears that initially there was no mention, and later what was put in is exactly as in the book.

Answer (score 0):

The quote in Matt's answer is taken from the second (or later) edition. In the original edition, it read

> ...some books of lore that he had made at various times, written in his spidery hand, and labelled on their red backs: Translations from the Elvish, by **B.B.**

Still no mention of any inlay, but we do learn

> the content [...] was preserved in that copy of the Red Book of Westmarch which was made in Gondor by the King's Writer Findegil [...].

This is a book that has copies found in royal libraries, so ornamentation is a possibility, but there is nothing definitive.